# keras to tf.keras Conversion: Dense layer dimensions not defined?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

So I've built a convnet using pure `keras`. It compiles and operates exactly as intended, but I need to convert it to use `tf.keras` so that I can make use of `tfmot`. Having read documentation, I attempted to convert it, only to get the following error:

`The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None.`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Original `keras` model:

```
input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
reshape_layer = keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 100, 1))(input_layer)
conv_layer_1 = keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(10, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(reshape_layer)
conv_layer_2 = keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(8, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_1)
conv_layer_3 = keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(6, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_2)
conv_layer_4 = keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_3)
conv_layer_5 = keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_4)
flatten_layer = keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_layer_5)
label_layer = keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(flatten_layer)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(label_layer)

model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

Converted `tf.keras` model:

```
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(100,))
reshape_layer = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 100, 1))(input_layer)
conv_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(10, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(reshape_layer)
conv_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(8, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_1)
conv_layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(6, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_2)
conv_layer_4 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_3)
conv_layer_5 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_4)
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_layer_5)
label_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(flatten_layer)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(label_layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
```

EDIT 1:

I thought maybe I could get around the issue by saving the `keras` model after creation and loading it as a `tf.keras` model immediately before compilation / training. That throws the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's few issues with your code. Fix them and you should be good to go,

### Issue 1: Use `Input` instead of `InputLayer`

The standard is to use `Input` layer instead of `InputLayer` (which infact uses `InputLayer` internally). You also need to change `input_shape` to `shape` if you are using `Input` layer.

```
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
```

### Issue 2: 2 `None` dimensions in the output

When you execute the following line, you get two `None` dimensions in your output.

```
reshape_layer = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 100, 1))(input_layer)
```

Which is why you are getting the above error. When defining the `Reshape` layer you don't define the `batch` dimension, which will be None. And that's the only dimension you can have as `None` if you want to use a `Dense` layer. Otherwise, the `Dense` layer cannot infer the shape of its weights (which is why you get the error). So change that to,

```
reshape_layer = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 100, 1))(input_layer)
```

The rest stays the same.

```
conv_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(10, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(reshape_layer)
conv_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(8, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_1)
conv_layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(6, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_2)
conv_layer_4 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_3)
conv_layer_5 = tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_4)
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(conv_layer_5)
label_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu")(flatten_layer)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(label_layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.summary()
```